# Difference between the declared size in inches and the size obtained using DisplayMetrics

Tags: android, android-screen

I have got a [Samsung Galaxy S4 Active](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_i9295_galaxy_s4_active-5446.php)

When I execute on Android, the following code:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
int width=dm.widthPixels;
int height=dm.heightPixels;
int dens=dm.densityDpi;
double wi=(double)width/(double)dens;
double hi=(double)height/(double)dens;
double x = Math.pow(wi,2);
double y = Math.pow(hi,2);
double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x+y);
```

I obtain

```
width = 1080
heigh = 1920
dens = 480
```

So, is the used formula is correct, `screenInches` is 4.589. But the specification said that the screenInches size is 5.

I have also tried with my [Samsung Galaxy SII](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_i9100_galaxy_s_ii-3621.php) that gives me:

```
width = 480
heigh = 800
dens = 240
```

that corresponds to a `screenInches` of 3.887 instead of 4.3 (as said in the specs)

Why there is this difference between the declared size in inches and the size I obtain?

**EDIT**: It seems that densityDpi returns one of these values: (120, 160, 213, 240, 320, 480 or 640 dpi).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can get the real screen density from DisplayMetrics.densityDpi. It can return only one of particular constant value.
[DisplayMetrics documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#densityDpi) says that

> The screen density expressed as dots-per-inch. May be either DENSITY_LOW, DENSITY_MEDIUM, or DENSITY_HIGH.

But [Android Compatibility Definition Document (CDD).](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/source.android.com/en//compatibility/android-cdd.pdf) provides a more comprehensive explanation

> Screen Density 
>   The Android UI framework defines a set of standard
>   logical densities to help application developers target application
>   resources. 
>   Device implementations MUST report one of the following
>   logical Android framework densities through the
>   android.util.DisplayMetrics APIs, and MUST execute applications at
>   this standard density. 
>   
> > 120 dpi, known as 'ldpi' 
>   
> > 160 dpi, known as 'mdpi'
>   
> > 213 dpi, known as 'tvdpi' 
>   
> > 240 dpi, known as 'hdpi' 
>   
> > 320 dpi, known as 'xhdpi' 
>   
> > 400 dpi, known as '400dpi' 
>   
> > 480 dpi, known as 'xxhdpi'
>   
> > 640 dpi, known as 'xxxhdpi' 
>   
>   Device implementations SHOULD define the
>   standard Android framework density that is numerically closest to the
>   physical density of the screen, unless that logical density pushes the
>   reported screen size below the minimum supported. If the standard
>   Android framework density that is numerically closest to the physical
>   density results in a screen size that is smaller than the smallest
>   supported compatible screen size (320 dp width), device
>   implementations SHOULD report the next lowest standard Android
>   framework density.

You can get the exact physical pixels per inch of the screen in the X and Y dimension from [DespalyMetrics.xdpi](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#xdpi) and [DespalyMetrics.ydpi](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#ydpi)

Answer (score 0):

`densityDpi` returns the screen density expressed as dots-per-inch, but this value is approximated.

`densityDpi` is calculated from `density` which is a logical density of display.This is a scaling factor for the Density Independent Pixel unit, where one DIP is one pixel on an approximately 160 dpi screen (for example a 240x320, 1.5"x2" screen), providing the baseline of the system's display. Thus on a 160dpi screen this density value will be 1; on a 120 dpi screen it would be .75; etc.

As said in the documentation:

```
This value does not exactly follow the real screen size (as given by xdpi and ydpi) , but rather is used to scale the size of the overall UI in steps based on gross changes in the display dpi.
```

So in order to obtain the correct DPI I can use `xdpi` and `ydpi`.

Applying these to my Samsung Galaxy S4 Active, I obtain:

xdpi = 442.451
ydpi = 439.351

My phone spec said ~441 ppi pixel density, so I think these value are correct.

So, getting the average value 440.901 DPI the result is:

```
screenInches = 4.9963
```