# Android DisplayMetrics inconsistent between devices

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, touch, dpi

I'm trying to use DPI and touch input in my unity game to recognise gestures consistently across android devices of different sizes.

For instance, I want my virtual thumbstick to be two inches from "full left" to "full right". Given the DPI of the screen, I can convert touches from pixels to inches like this: `inchesFromStickCenter = pixelsFromStickCenter/dpi`.

To get DPI, unity offers `Screen.dpi` but I was getting inconsistent results across devices. Sometimes the thumbstick was way too big, sometimes way too small. Instead I went straight to Android's DisplayMetrics, where I could get `xdpi`, `ydpi`, and `densityDpi`. From this question [Difference between the declared size in inches and the size obtained using DisplayMetrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23475200/difference-between-the-declared-size-in-inches-and-the-size-obtained-using-displ) I see that densityDpi is a rounded value, and I should probably be using xdpi or ydpi.

I tested things by trying to compute the width of the screen in inches (my is landscape, all these examples assume landscape). When I divide the screen pixel width (1280) by xdpi (195.4) on my 1st gen N7, it overestimates the screen width by half an inch (6.55 inches, compared to just under 6 when measured with a rule). When I divide by densityDpi (213), it's a much better answer. The wikipedia page for the N7 says dpi is 215, which would also give a great answer.

When I test on my Galaxy S2, the xdpi (217) gives a good screen size estimate, and the densityDpi (240) gives an underestimate by a third of an inch.

So I can't depend on either of these numbers! Why is neither N7 stat nothing like the wikipedia page? Is this a silly way of trying to convert pixels to real-world inches? What should I be doing instead?

Cheers!

Comment: Did you use this function for conversion? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238883/what-is-the-correct-way-to-specify-dimensions-in-dip-from-java-code

Comment: I'm using pixels and inches, not dips. if you're suggesting I should try dips, it'd be great if you posted an answer with more details.

Comment: I ended up having a bunch of different values hard-coded to different DPIs to get consistent behaviour. It was very annoying. Although now I read the question I'm wondering if I should have been using the ydpi value, since my games were always in landscape? That project is shelved so I'm not going to go back and check.